# Java Sockets Direct Protocol

Tags: java, sockets

As we know the Sockets Direct Protocol (SDP) provides access to high performance network connections, such as that provided by InfiniBand

can any one please give me any good example of how can i use Sockets Direct Protocol (SDP) of java ?

Comment: Are you looking for sample code? The tutorial seems a good start: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sdp/sockets/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running a recent version of Solaris or OpenSolaris I think you are all set to try stuff out.

Linux requires use of the [libsdp](http://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/libsdp/) library and [external kernel modules](http://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/OFED/) available from OpenFabrics (OFED), there seems to be strong desire to get the modules into Linux mainline but OFED guys seem to be rubbing the kernel developers up the wrong way over some of the issues involved.

There's a useful [setup guide](http://pkg-ofed.alioth.debian.org/howto/infiniband-howto.html) for Infiniband under Debian Linux which gives details on how to set up and compile the OFED kernel modules and the libsdp library etc. Once you have that done you can follow the [SDP section](http://pkg-ofed.alioth.debian.org/howto/infiniband-howto-7.html) of that how-to in order to get SDP working and tested.

After that I think it is as simple as getting a recent JDK7 snapshot, [currently at M12](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html), and trying stuff out. [Set up your config](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sdp/sockets/file.html) and create connections between addresses specified in your SDP config, all done via the [same APIs as network sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sdp/sockets/supported.html), i.e. Socket for 'old' IO, and SocketChannel for NIO (or even AIO in JDK7 :). As far as I can see, once you have followed the set up guides and configured the addresses that will use SDP the JVM will use SDP based Sockets/SocketChannels whenever you provide addresses within the SDP mapped range. So your existing networking code that uses sockets should be able to use the SDP connections transparently, just at blazingly fast speeds and tiny latencies.

Windows users are out of luck for the time being, as far as I can tell.

Also:

[Alan Bateman's SDP blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/sockets_direct_protocol) (Oracle JDK SDP lead)

Comment: SDP is deprecated and OFED no more come with SDP support. Hence Java's SDP also fails. Any solutions?